# Concurrent access to Java servlet's service method

Tags: java, servlets

Background:  I am using hibernate objects for database access.
inside my servlet's doGet I have:

```
Account account=getUserAccountHibernateObject();
doWorkOnAccount(account);
decreaseAccountBalanceAndSaveToDB(account);
```

Since servlet allows concurrent access, the accountBalance is really messed up sometimes.  I have several questions:

1. What's the best practice here?  Should my thread implement SingleThreadModel to prevent concurrent access?  Or synchronize everything in doGet?
2. Should I do the following?   What's the right thing to do in hibernate?

   ```
   Account account=getUserAccountHibernateObject();
   doWorkOnAccount(account);
   account=getUserAccountHibernateObject();
   decreaseAccountBalanceAndSaveToDB(account); //also synchronize this method.
   ```

Edit:
tentative solution:
thanks to the link provided by the answers, I think I need to span DB transaction throughout the servlet request:

```
beginTransaction();
try{
Account account=getUserAccountHibernateObject();
doWorkOnAccount(account);
decreaseAccountBalanceAndSaveToDB(account); 
commitTransaction();
}catch(Exception ep){
  rollBackTransaction();
}finally{
   closeSession();
}
```

if there's any hibernate/db guru out there thing there's something wrong with this, please let me know.

Comment: Servlet can be used concurrently, but not it's service() local variables. So servlet concurrency is not the issue here. I suspect your problem is the lack of DB transactions or improper locking of the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use Transactions. There's a [section of the Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#transactions) that covers this, especially the "Unit of work" part.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that part of your code stores or accesses data in static variables or is otherwise improperly thread-safe.

I have worked on relatively large webapps which have never needed to provide excessive synchronization (and certainly not resort to single-thread access) to avoid concurrency problems.

It's hard to suggest what specifically to fix without seeing more of how things are laid out.